# Working with arrays and manipulating them - Computer Science Homework

Tags: java, arrays

The instructions here were to create a BowlingScores class and BowlingScoresViewer client class: In the BowlingScores class, create a method named printScores():

- This class should keep track of scores for multiple bowlers. Scores are integer values
  between 0 and 300.
- Create a normal one-dimensional array to keep track of bowler nicknames. Use an
  initializer list to populate this array with 6 bowler nicknames (6 elements).
- Create a two-dimensional array to keep track of multiple scores per bowler

  - Each bowler has bowled 4 games.
    -Each row number of this array will correspond to the index of the bowler from the “bowler
    nicknames” array you just created.
  - Each column represents one of the four scores for the bowler.
  - Use an initializer list to populate the scores for each bowler.
- Write a loop to process the two arrays as follows:

  - Loop through each bowler in the bowler array
  - For each bowler, loop through the corresponding scores for that bowler
  - Output the bowler nickname and a list of his/her scores to the console similar to the following.
  - Also, calculate the average score for the bowler

[Here is the link to the BowlerScoresViewer  class](http://www.wsfcs.k12.nc.us/cms/lib/NC01001395/Centricity/domain/173/2010-2011/homework/java%20concepts/BowlingScoresViewer.txt)

[Here is the link to the BowlerScores class](http://www.wsfcs.k12.nc.us/cms/lib/NC01001395/Centricity/domain/173/2010-2011/homework/java%20concepts/BowlingScores.txt)

Right now here is what I have in terms of code I need help with finding the averages and making sure I am doing this right.:

```
package javaconcepts;

// import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

//BowlingScores is used to practice using parallel arrays and 2-dimensional arrays

public class BowlingScores_MatthewBall 
{
    public void printScores() 
    {
        System.out.println("BOWLING SCORES:");
        String[] bowlers = {"L'Carpetron Dookmarriot", "Jackmerius Tacktheritrix", "Hingle McCringleberry", "Beezer Twelve Washingbeard", "X-Wing @Aliciousness", "Shakiraquan T.G.I.F. Carter"};
        int[][] bowlerScores = {{110, 90, 160, 140, 110},     // row 0
                                {92, 96, 80, 112, 204},     // row 1
                                {200, 200, 200, 190, 210},     // row 2                                        
                                {103, 90, 90, 150, 170},    // row 3
                                {118, 120, 116, 102, 200},    // row 4
                                {96, 96, 80, 112, 200}};    // row 5



/*      for (int i = 0; i < bowlers[i].length; i++)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x < bowlerScores[x].length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("L'Carpetron Dookmarriot bowled games of " + bowlerScores[x] + " which results in an average of " + ".");
                System.out.println("Jackmerius Tacktheritrix bowled games of " + bowlerScores[1] + " which results in an average of " + ".");
                System.out.println("Hingle McCringleberry bowled games of " + bowlerScores[2] + " which results in an average of " + ".");
                System.out.println("Beezer Twelve Washingbeard bowled games of " + bowlerScores[3] + " which results in an average of " + ".");
                System.out.println("X-Wing @Aliciousness bowled games of " + bowlerScores[4] + " which results in an average of " + ".");
                System.out.println("Shakiraquan T.G.I.F. Carter bowled games of " + bowlerScores[5] + " which results in an average of " + ".");
            }
        }*/

        for (int row = 0; row < bowlers.length; row++)  //loops thru rows
        { 
           System.out.println("");
           System.out.print(bowlers[row] + " bowled games of " );

           for (int col = 0; col < bowlerScores[0].length; col++) //loops thru columns
           {  
              System.out.print( bowlerScores[row][col] + ", " ); 
           }
           System.out.print( "which results in an average of " );
           for (int col = 0; col < bowlerScores[0].length; col++) //loops thru columns
           {   
                  System.out.print(bowlerScores[1][2]/bowlerScores[0].length); 
           }

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the average:
Set up an integer "total" as 0.
Then create for loop to add up each to total. 
After the for loop, you divide total by bowlerScores[#].length.

This code is for a single row array; obviously you would have to edit for multiple columns.

> for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
>
> ```
>    total = total + array[i];
> ```
>
> }
>
> int avg = total / array.length;
>
> return avg;

Now you can do this six different times, and store 6 different avg variables.

Also, ideally, with the for loop you use to print out each person and their name, you would use the string at each position from the bowlers array, and so rather than having 6 different print lines, you would have one. This is also useful because you could then input any names rather than being stuck with those, which honestly rather defeats the purpose of putting them in an array at all.

If you make the above change instead of 6 for loops with 6 different avg variables, you have one that is updated in each loop.

Should look something like this...

> for (int x = 0; x < bowlerScores[x].length; i++)
>               {
>
> ```
>            System.out.println(bowlers[x] + " bowled games of " + bowlerScores[x] + " which results in an average of " + ".");
> ```

You might have to double check that though, I haven't worked with many arrays that had more than one column (admittedly a beginner myself).

Comment: So what part of the code should I take out or change?

Comment: For the average? You need to add a for loop. You can either do 6 different ones, for each player, or make the second change as well and then you can make a for loop find the average for each player.
Rephrased, you need a for loop to add up each score, and either a for loop to calculate the average for each player or 6 for loops to add up the average for each player.

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner so its better for me to see your suggestions in code. Not just words I guess

Comment: EDIT: will post code to original answer obviously posting code in a comment is not a good idea

Comment: Does this answer your question, or are there still issues?

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid that you're all wrong, except you've got the loop syntax right.  Then you go ahead and manually print all the array values every time you go through the loop.  Which you probably already know!  I'll give you that piece, and see if you can get everything going from there:

```
System.out.println(bowlers[x]);
```

That will print out all the bowler names.  From there, follow the instructions given, which are quite clear.  You'll need to work out how to initialize your values in your bowlerScores array; you're only putting in one dimension.  You need also to put the number of the bowler in your bowlers array, to tie them together.